# Criei um formulário dentro do meu site para ser enviado ao meu email, não está chegando na caixa de entrada. O que pode ser?

Tags: php, phpmailer

https://facasozinho.com/fale.html

No mesmo dia desinstalei o wordpress manualmente, então não sei se houve conflito com o .htacess original com os outros 2 arquivos (.htacess) que continham do Wordpress.

```
//TRECHO DE CÓDIGO
<?php
    
    if(isset($POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){
    
       $nome = addslashes($_POST['name']);
       $email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
       $mensagem = addslashes($_POST['message']);
    
    
       $to = "faca@facasozinho.com";
       $subject = "Contato - Sugestão FZ";
       $body = "Nome: ".$nome. "\r\n".
            "Email: ".$email."\r\n".
            "Mensagem ".$mensagem;
    
       $header = "From:fzzsozinho@gmail.com"."\r\n". 
                "Reply - To:".$email."\e\n".
                "x=Mailer:PHP/".phpversion();
   
       if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$header))
       {    
          echo("Email enviado com sucesso!");
        } else {
          echo("O Email não pode ser enviado");
        }
    
    }
    
?>
```

Obs: Caso possa me responder de uma forma que eu aprenda a solucionar e não que tenha a resposta na mão ficaria agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está no `if`, veja que nenhuma informação é retornada, o response está vazio, indicando que não entra neste IF.

Acontece que errou o nome do array `$_POST`, você digitou `$POST['email']` ao invés de `$_POST['email']`, provavelmente irá funcionar ao corrigir:

`if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){`

Comment: @matheus-gamisz se a resposta resolveu seu problema, agradeço se marcar ela como aceita

Comment: Mais um descuido comum quando se está aprendendo uma nova linguagem, acha que usar uma IDE própria da linguagem como PHP storm ajudaria ou isso é comum? Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Meu amigo, escrever nome de variáveis é um descuido comum para todos, principalmente se não está usando um IDE, fique tranquilo. Mas sim, usar uma IDE auxilia muito na produtividade e qualidade do código. Eu uso PHP Storm já há uns 2 anos, mas por muitos anos antes usei Netbeans para trabalhar com PHP, você estará bem com qualquer um deles.